# Смена обоев рабочего стола не всегда работает

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, picturebox

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, IntPtr lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

private void picturebox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  var dropfiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
  foreach (var file in dropfiles)
  {

    var filename = getFileName(file);
    ShowWallpapeR.Image = Image.FromFile(file);
    SystemParametersInfo
    (
       SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 1, Marshal.StringToBSTR(file), 
       SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE  |  SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE
    );
  }
}

static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = new List<string> { ".JPG", ".BMP"};
private void picturebox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false))
   {
     var allowFilesDrop = true;
     foreach (var f in (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
     {
       allowFilesDrop = ImageExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToUpperInvariant());
     }
     if (allowFilesDrop)
     {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
     }
   }
}
```

На windows 7 не всегда меняются обои, есть ли этому решение?

Comment: посмотри что тебе возвращает SystemParametersInfo

Comment: @Grundy, Исключения? если исключения, то ничего не выпадает, пробовал разные варианты использования, даже через реестр не хочет ставить некоторые `.jpg` форматы. Как работает стандартный windows смена обоев?

Comment: Посмотри определение функции `SystemParametersInfo` - `private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, IntPtr lpvParam, int fuWinIni);` - заметь, что у нее есть **возвращаемое значение** типа `int`. У тебя оно нигде не проверяется. Я тебе и написал - посмотри что именно тебе вернулось. Причем тут какие-то исключения?

Comment: [If the function succeeds, the return value is a nonzero value.
If the function fails, the return value is zero. **To get extended error information, call GetLastError.**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx)